# What is the meaning of the dotted links that connect a latent variable and a manifest variable in an SEM?

Tags: r-lavaan, sem, jamovi

i conduct SEM with lavaan under Jamovi (SEMLj), and i can't understand what do represent dotted links that connect a latent variable and a manifest variable.

[My Model and path diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXbiv.png)

Is it possible to transform them into a continuous link?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the dashed lines are nonzero fixed (rather than estimated) parameters.  Parameters that are fixed to zero are merely excluded from the diagram.  But the paths fixed to 1 are following a familiar identification constrain that you can read about in an SEM/CFA textbook.